# Running a source script to load an enviromnent when running python interpreter in pycharm

Tags: pycharm, root-framework

I am using a certain package called ROOT by CERN for data analysis. It is originally written in c++ but there is an implementation for python as well. To import it in python I need to open the terminal and run the following command:

```
source /path/to/file/thisroot.sh
```

As far as I know this sets up an environment in the terminal. Now I can import ROOT to python as well as starting the interactive ROOT application (but only in the terminal I executed the .sh file with).

Sadly I don't know that much about virtual environments. Is it possible to run the `thisroot.sh` script in pycharm so I can import ROOT directly in pycharm?